# Стоит ли по-разному называть JQuery и javascript переменные?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-style

Я слышал, что перед переменной jQuery следует ставить $, чтобы не путать их, это так?

Comment: http://frontender.info/writing-better-jquery-code/

Comment: `jQuery` теперь не `javascript`?

Comment: Исключительно вопрос договоренности между разработчиками. Я так не делаю например, и код где так делается вижу довольно редко. Если Вы пишете нормальный код а не тысячестроковые функции то проблемы быстро отличить jquery выборку от чего-то еще - просто не встает.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму тут интереснее со свойствами, хранящимися в объектах. Если функции на 1000 строк и правда глупость - то класс на 1000 строк может вырасти запросто.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, согласен, Вы привели пример где это может быть полезно и такое я встречал когда-то в проектах на основе бэкбона. Но все-таки с распространением фреймворков берущих управление DOM на себя, сохранение какой-то jQuery выборки в свойстве тысячестрокового класса - не очень распространенная практика)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму *вот только в прошлом месяце в очередной раз переподключал select2 к knockoutjs... Четыре класса, наследование, примеси... А все из-за того, что из коробки оно не умеет работать с динамическим списком опций!*

Answer (score 1):

Ставить или не ставить, вот в чём вопрос...

Зависит от стиля писания кода.
Если кто-то считает что единый стиль нафиг не нужен, читаем [это](http://frontender.info/why-coding-style-matters/) и, после обращения в веру стайл-гайдов, веруем, например, в [это](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml).

Я же думаю что лучший способ определить `jQuery`-объект - подсказки IDE на основе `JSDoc` или подобном.